# My Asynchronous function in typescript is returning a promise { <pending> } instead of value

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, es6-promise

I have this typescript code where I'm hitting the POST url  function with another function .But, I'm getting the promise {  } instead of value while trying to fetch the response in another variable. the code snippet is below:-

```
const fetchCellId = async (req: Request, res: Response,next: NextFunction)=>{
    const cellId = req.query.cellId as string;
    let results;
  
    try {
      results =   getCellId(req, res, next);
      results.then(data =>{
        return data;
      });
      
      console.log('look78');
      console.log(results);
      //if (results.json.length === 0) {
      //  throw "API returned an empty array";
      //}
      await redisClient.set(cellId, JSON.stringify(results), {
        
        EX: 180,
        NX: true,
      });
  console.log('look 54')
      res.send({
        fromCache: false,
        data: results,
      });
      console.log('look 56') 
    
  }catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(404).send("Data unavailable");
    }
  }

const getCellId = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    // get CellID details
    console.log('look 10');
    let id: string = req.query.cellId as string;
    console.log(id);
    let cid = id.substring(0, 5);
    let lac = id.substring(12,16);
    let mcc = id.substring(6, 9);
    let mnc = id[10];
    console.log(cid);
    console.log(lac);
    console.log(mcc);
    console.log(mnc);
    let response: AxiosResponse = await axios.post(`https://eu1.unwiredlabs.com/v2/process.php`, {
        'token': 'pk.ccd04*****######6',
        'radio': 'lte',
        'mcc': mcc,
        'mnc': mnc,
        'cells': [{
            'lac': lac,
            'cid': cid
        }]
    });
    // return response
   const  cellIdRes = await res.status(200).json(
        
      {

      "lng": response.data.lon,
      "lat": response.data.lat,
      "acc": response.data.accuracy
  }
  );
  console.log(cellIdRes);
  return cellIdRes;

    
   

    
    
};
```

As you can see  in try block I'm trying to invoke getCellId & assigning the value to results.But it is fetching promise pending to results.

```
try {
      results =   getCellId(req, res, next);
      results.then(data =>{
        return data;
      });
```

I have already tried these 2 ways & they are not working

1

```
results =   getCellId(req, res, next).then(data =>{
        console.log(data);
      });
```

This is giving promise pending to results

2

```
results =  await getCellId(req, res, next);
```

This one is giving some big server response which looks like this:

```
<ref *2> ServerResponse {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    finish: [ [Function: bound resOnFinish], [Function: onevent] ],
    end: [Function: onevent]
  },
  _eventsCount: 2,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  outputData: [],
  outputSize: 0,
  writable: true,
  destroyed: false,
  _last: false,
  chunkedEncoding: false,
  shouldKeepAlive: true,
  maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
  _defaultKeepAlive: true,
  useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
  sendDate: true,
  _removedConnection: false,
  _removedContLen: false,
  _removedTE: false,
  _contentLength: 41,
  _hasBody: true,
  _trailer: '',
  finished: true,
  _headerSent: true,
  _closed: false,
  socket: <ref *1> Socket {
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _parent: null,
    _host: null,
    _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: true,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: true,
      constructed: true,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: true,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: true,
      destroyed: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: false,
      dataEmitted: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      end: [Array],
      timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
      data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
      error: [Array],
      close: [Array],
      drain: [Function: bound socketOnDrain],
      resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
      pause: [Function: onSocketPause]
    },
    _eventsCount: 8,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: false,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: [Object],
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 1,
      constructed: true,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
    },
    allowHalfOpen: true,
    _sockname: null,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: Server {
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      requestTimeout: 300000,
      headersTimeout: 60000,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      connectionsCheckingInterval: 30000,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      noDelay: true,
      keepAlive: false,
      keepAliveInitialDelay: 0,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      maxRequestsPerSocket: 0,
      _connectionKey: '6::::6060',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 10,
      [Symbol(http.server.connections)]: ConnectionsList {},
      [Symbol(http.server.connectionsCheckingInterval)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 30000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 1911,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound checkConnections],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: 30000,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 9,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 1
      },
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    _server: Server {
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      requestTimeout: 300000,
      headersTimeout: 60000,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      connectionsCheckingInterval: 30000,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      noDelay: true,
      keepAlive: false,
      keepAliveInitialDelay: 0,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      maxRequestsPerSocket: 0,
      _connectionKey: '6::::6060',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 10,
      [Symbol(http.server.connections)]: ConnectionsList {},
      [Symbol(http.server.connectionsCheckingInterval)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 30000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 1911,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound checkConnections],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: 30000,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 9,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 1
      },
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    parser: HTTPParser {
      '0': null,
      '1': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
      '2': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
      '3': [Function: parserOnBody],
      '4': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
      '5': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
      '6': [Function: bound onParserTimeout],
      _headers: [],
      _url: '',
      socket: [Circular *1],
      incoming: [IncomingMessage],
      outgoing: null,
      maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
      _consumed: true,
      onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming],
      [Symbol(resource_symbol)]: [HTTPServerAsyncResource]
    },
    on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    setEncoding: [Function: socketSetEncoding],
    _paused: false,
    _httpMessage: [Circular *2],
    _peername: { address: '::1', family: 'IPv6', port: 60231 },
    [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 16,
    [Symbol(kHandle)]: TCP {
      reading: true,
      onconnection: null,
      _consumed: true,
      [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
    },
    [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
    [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: false,
    [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
  },
  _header: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n' +
    'X-Powered-By: Express\r\n' +
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n' +
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept, Authorization\r\n' +
    'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n' +
    'Content-Length: 41\r\n' +
    'ETag: W/"29-afqpvhUsI3BqVKtdfXeXBFSPr/E"\r\n' +
    'Date: Sun, 23 Oct 2022 21:55:57 GMT\r\n' +
    'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
    'Keep-Alive: timeout=5\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
  _keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
  _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
  req: IncomingMessage {
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: null,
      ended: true,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: false,
      constructed: true,
      sync: true,
      needReadable: false,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      destroyed: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: true,
      dataEmitted: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    socket: <ref *1> Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: null,
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 8,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: [Server],
      _server: [Server],
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      setEncoding: [Function: socketSetEncoding],
      _paused: false,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *2],
      _peername: [Object],
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 16,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
    },
    httpVersionMajor: 1,
    httpVersionMinor: 1,
    httpVersion: '1.1',
    complete: true,
    rawHeaders: [ 'HOST', 'localhost:6060' ],
    rawTrailers: [],
    aborted: false,
    upgrade: false,
    url: '/byCellId?cellId=26902-242-2-2305',
    method: 'GET',
    statusCode: null,
    statusMessage: null,
    client: <ref *1> Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: null,
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 8,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: [Server],
      _server: [Server],
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      setEncoding: [Function: socketSetEncoding],
      _paused: false,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *2],
      _peername: [Object],
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 16,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
    },
    _consuming: false,
    _dumped: false,
    next: [Function: next],
    baseUrl: '',
    originalUrl: '/byCellId?cellId=26902-242-2-2305',
    _parsedUrl: Url {
      protocol: null,
      slashes: null,
      auth: null,
      host: null,
      port: null,
      hostname: null,
      hash: null,
      search: '?cellId=26902-242-2-2305',
      query: 'cellId=26902-242-2-2305',
      pathname: '/byCellId',
      path: '/byCellId?cellId=26902-242-2-2305',
      href: '/byCellId?cellId=26902-242-2-2305',
      _raw: '/byCellId?cellId=26902-242-2-2305'
    },
    params: {},
    query: { cellId: '26902-242-2-2305' },
    res: [Circular *2],
    _startAt: [ 285179, 787753500 ],
    _startTime: 2022-10-23T21:55:57.719Z,
    _remoteAddress: '::1',
    body: {},
    route: Route { path: '/byCellId', stack: [Array], methods: [Object] },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kHeaders)]: { host: 'localhost:6060' },
    [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 2,
    [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
    [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
  },
  _sent100: false,
  _expect_continue: false,
  _maxRequestsPerSocket: 0,
  locals: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _startAt: [ 285179, 995961100 ],
  _startTime: 2022-10-23T21:55:57.928Z,
  writeHead: [Function: writeHead],
  __onFinished: [Function: listener] { queue: [ [Function: logRequest] ] },
  statusCode: 200,
  statusMessage: 'OK',
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
  [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
  [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
    'x-powered-by': [ 'X-Powered-By', 'Express' ],
    'access-control-allow-origin': [ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*' ],
    'access-control-allow-headers': [
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
      'origin, X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept, Authorization'
    ],
    'content-type': [ 'Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8' ],
    'content-length': [ 'Content-Length', '41' ],
    etag: [ 'ETag', 'W/"29-afqpvhUsI3BqVKtdfXeXBFSPr/E"' ]
  },
  [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
}
look78
<ref *2> ServerResponse {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    finish: [ [Function: bound resOnFinish], [Function: onevent] ],
    end: [Function: onevent]
  },
  _eventsCount: 2,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  outputData: [],
  outputSize: 0,
  writable: true,
  destroyed: false,
  _last: false,
  chunkedEncoding: false,
  shouldKeepAlive: true,
  maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
  _defaultKeepAlive: true,
  useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
  sendDate: true,
  _removedConnection: false,
  _removedContLen: false,
  _removedTE: false,
  _contentLength: 41,
  _hasBody: true,
  _trailer: '',
  finished: true,
  _headerSent: true,
  _closed: false,
  socket: <ref *1> Socket {
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _parent: null,
    _host: null,
    _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: true,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: true,
      constructed: true,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: true,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: true,
      destroyed: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: false,
      dataEmitted: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      end: [Array],
      timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
      data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
      error: [Array],
      close: [Array],
      drain: [Function: bound socketOnDrain],
      resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
      pause: [Function: onSocketPause]
    },
    _eventsCount: 8,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: false,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: [Object],
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 1,
      constructed: true,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
    },
    allowHalfOpen: true,
    _sockname: null,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: Server {
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      requestTimeout: 300000,
      headersTimeout: 60000,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      connectionsCheckingInterval: 30000,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      noDelay: true,
      keepAlive: false,
      keepAliveInitialDelay: 0,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      maxRequestsPerSocket: 0,
      _connectionKey: '6::::6060',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 10,
      [Symbol(http.server.connections)]: ConnectionsList {},
      [Symbol(http.server.connectionsCheckingInterval)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 30000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 1911,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound checkConnections],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: 30000,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 9,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 1
      },
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    _server: Server {
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      requestTimeout: 300000,
      headersTimeout: 60000,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      connectionsCheckingInterval: 30000,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      noDelay: true,
      keepAlive: false,
      keepAliveInitialDelay: 0,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      maxRequestsPerSocket: 0,
      _connectionKey: '6::::6060',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 10,
      [Symbol(http.server.connections)]: ConnectionsList {},
      [Symbol(http.server.connectionsCheckingInterval)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 30000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 1911,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound checkConnections],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: 30000,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 9,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 1
      },
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    parser: HTTPParser {
      '0': null,
      '1': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
      '2': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
      '3': [Function: parserOnBody],
      '4': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
      '5': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
      '6': [Function: bound onParserTimeout],
      _headers: [],
      _url: '',
      socket: [Circular *1],
      incoming: [IncomingMessage],
      outgoing: null,
      maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
      _consumed: true,
      onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming],
      [Symbol(resource_symbol)]: [HTTPServerAsyncResource]
    },
    on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    setEncoding: [Function: socketSetEncoding],
    _paused: false,
    _httpMessage: [Circular *2],
    _peername: { address: '::1', family: 'IPv6', port: 60231 },
    [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 16,
    [Symbol(kHandle)]: TCP {
      reading: true,
      onconnection: null,
      _consumed: true,
      [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
    },
    [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
    [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: false,
    [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
  },
  _header: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n' +
    'X-Powered-By: Express\r\n' +
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n' +
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept, Authorization\r\n' +
    'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n' +
    'Content-Length: 41\r\n' +
    'ETag: W/"29-afqpvhUsI3BqVKtdfXeXBFSPr/E"\r\n' +
    'Date: Sun, 23 Oct 2022 21:55:57 GMT\r\n' +
    'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
    'Keep-Alive: timeout=5\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
  _keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
  _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
  req: IncomingMessage {
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: null,
      ended: true,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: false,
      constructed: true,
      sync: true,
      needReadable: false,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      destroyed: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: true,
      dataEmitted: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    socket: <ref *1> Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: null,
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 8,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: [Server],
      _server: [Server],
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      setEncoding: [Function: socketSetEncoding],
      _paused: false,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *2],
      _peername: [Object],
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 16,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
    },
    httpVersionMajor: 1,
    httpVersionMinor: 1,
    httpVersion: '1.1',
    complete: true,
    rawHeaders: [ 'HOST', 'localhost:6060' ],
    rawTrailers: [],
    aborted: false,
    upgrade: false,
    url: '/byCellId?cellId=26902-242-2-2305',
    method: 'GET',
    statusCode: null,
    statusMessage: null,
    client: <ref *1> Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: null,
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 8,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
```

Comment: There's a lot wrong here starting with this:       `results.then(data =>{  return data;  });` which does nothing useful at all.  I don't know what you think it's doing, but it's not affecting what's in the `results` variable (which is a promise) and it's not returning from your function (it's just returning from the `.then()` callback.

Comment: results.then(data =>{  return data;  }) ---agree it has no impact. I did it to fix the promise issue by looking at different stack overflow issue logs. Even if I remove it, the issue remains same regarding promise pending

Answer (score -2):

All async functions return a promise...

to get the desired value
use this

```
const myValue = await MyAyncFuction(...)
```

what I mean is this put `await` for all async function calls...  to make run synchronously (one by one not putting ur result in pending)

that everywhere you fetch use `await`

Comment: you meant this:- results =  await getCellId(req, res, next); ----this is not working

Comment: what mean is this put await for all async function calls...

Comment: In my question itself I have mentioned  that I have already tried doing this:- results =  await getCellId(req, res, next);  ---& this is not working